# Mathematica is not giving a solution for values different from Zero

Tags: equation-solving

Here is my equation:

```
Solve[(698 *x)/33 == a, x, Assumptions -> { a == Integers , a/698 == Integers, x == PositiveIntegers}]
```

The output is an empty ensemble. However, there is a solution for x =! 0. For example when x = 23034, then a will be 487204 and 487204/698=698.

What am I doing wrong and why can't I get an answer?
Thanks

Comment: Try `Solve[(698*x)/33 == a, x, 
 Assumptions -> {Element[a, Integers], Element[x, PositiveIntegers]}]` gives solution. Also you can do `FindInstance[698*x == 33*a, {x, a}, PositiveIntegers, 10];` to pick some instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions.

```
sol = Solve[{(698*x)/33 == a, a/698 == k, x > 0}, {a, x, k}, Integers]
```

```
FindInstance[{(698*x)/33 == a, a/698 == k, x > 0}, {a, x, 
  k}, Integers, 10]
```